# How to hide certain category with its subcategory in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

if ( is_product_category( 'ukhta')) {

```
foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

  if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'siktivkar','divani_po_akcii', 'akcii_uhta', 'akcii_siktivkar', 'divani_akkordeoni_siktivkar','kresla_siktivkar','modulnie_divani_siktivkar', 'pufi-i-banketki-siktivkar', 'sofi-i-kushetki-siktivkar', 'chehlovie_divani_siktivkar', 'uglovie_divani_siktivkar',  'divani_evroknijki', 'divani_-knijki_siktivkar' ) ) ) {
    $new_terms[] = $term;
  }

}

$terms = $new_terms;
```

}

return $terms;
}

Comment: If I go to subcategory of Ukhta - I see another category too

Comment: How to point in php hook like this : If (is_product_category('ukhta') || subcategory ('ukhta')) {...}?

Comment: he result of this hook is displayed on the subcategory page in the sidebar on the left all categories and subcategories. But when you click on a certain subcategory - when you switch to this subcategory, including in the category. And only a certain category with a subcategory is needed, the subcategory of which was clicked.

Comment: add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {

$new_terms = array();

// если находится в товарной категории и на странице магазина

if ( is_product_category('это_категория_1')) {

foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

  if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'это_категория_2','это_категория_3', 'это_подкатегория_1_категории3', 'это_подкатегория_1_категории_2' ) ) )